# How to create the update method (String id, Item resourceItem) using SpringJPAMongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-jpa

How to create the update method (String id, Item resourceItem) using SpringJPAMongoDB? The idea is not to use getters and completely copy all fields from the resource object into the object from the database with the id from the signature.

```
@Transactional
    public void update(String id, Order order) {

        Order existingOrder = findById(id);

        if (existingOrder != null) {

            BeanUtils.copyProperties(order, existingOrder, "id");

            System.out.println(existingOrder);

            orderRepository.deleteById(id);
            orderRepository.save(existingOrder);
        }
    }
```

At the moment I use such a code with deletion of the previous record, which I would like to avoid, in the case of no use of deletion or questioning change id to the object of the resource and its further saving avoids the error of duplicate key. All resources that have found offer either replacement of one particular field through the setter or replacement of all fields (except id) again through the setters. I’d appreciate your help.

All resources that have found offer either replacement of one particular field through the setter or replacement of all fields (except id) again through the setters.